# MySQL GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP - want to ROLLUP all permutations

Tags: mysql, sql

Take for example this table (let's call it `BIN_TABLE`):

```
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|    0 |    0 |
|    0 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    0 |
+------+------+
```

I want to roll it up, so I do:

```
SELECT   A, B, COUNT(*)
FROM     BIN_TABLE
GROUP BY A, B WITH ROLLUP;
```

And I get:

```
+------+------+----------+
| A    | B    | COUNT(*) |
+------+------+----------+
|    0 |    0 |        1 |
|    0 |    1 |        1 |
|    0 | NULL |        2 |
|    1 |    0 |        1 |
|    1 |    1 |        1 |
|    1 | NULL |        2 |
| NULL | NULL |        4 |
+------+------+----------+
```

This is an example of how `WITH ROLLUP` uses the order of the fields I put in the `GROUP BY` clause.

I would like to also have the following lines in the result:

```
| NULL |    1 |        2 |
| NULL |    0 |        2 |
```

Which would mean that I have all of the rolled-up permutations.

Is this possible to do without resorting to this:

```
SELECT   A, B, COUNT(*)
FROM     BIN_TABLE
GROUP BY A, B WITH ROLLUP
UNION
SELECT   NULL, B, COUNT(*)
FROM     BIN_TABLE
GROUP BY B
```

(I use MySQL 5.6, if it matters)

Comment: I would like to add to my question then: Why use `WITH ROLLUP` at all? Why not just plain out implement this myself by `UNION`ing more and more queries together, each NULLifying a different field? Is there any benefit to `WITH ROLLUP` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe `UNION` is the only way.  You could however use `UNION ALL` (rather than the implicit `UNION DISTINCT`) to save from needlessly searching for duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

According the function of roll-up modifier, there are already all rolled-up permutations in your results.

Please look at these results.

```
+------+------+----------+
| A    | B    | COUNT(*) |
+------+------+----------+
|    0 |    0 |        1 |
|    0 |    1 |        1 |
|    0 | NULL |        2 |
|    1 |    0 |        1 |
|    1 |    1 |        1 |
|    1 | NULL |        2 |
| NULL | NULL |        4 |
+------+------+----------+
```

Here, 3rd record and 6th record are the rolled-up permutations.
So we can get the result by a following sql.

```
SELECT * from 
    (select a,b,count(*) from 
      bin_table group by a,b with rollup) total 
 order by total.b desc,a;

+------+------+----------+
| a    | b    | count(*) |
+------+------+----------+
|    0 |    1 |        1 |
|    1 |    1 |        1 |
|    0 |    0 |        1 |
|    1 |    0 |        1 |
| NULL | NULL |        4 |
|    0 | NULL |        2 |
|    1 | NULL |        2 |
+------+------+----------+
  7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here, 6th record and 7th record are the rolled-up permutations.
And I think that it will make the performance better.

Thanks,

Comment: Please read my question again - these are not all of the rolled-up permutations because two are missing. For all rolled-up permutations to exist, you would have to have 3^2 rows (0, 1 and NULL possibilities for each column). You can see that in the last example output I have on the question.